# Creating shared object library to switch out loaded methods

Tags: c, android, function-hooking

Is it possible to create a dynamic library `libXXX.so` with android ndk that has a function that switches out methods in loaded classes in the dvm and call it from any apk ?

There are functions within `libdvm.so` to find loaded classes that could be used. Is this not as useful as I think it is or am I missing how difficult it is ?

The only example I found of someone doing this is explained in this blog post:

- [Android hacking: replacing system classes methods with your own](http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-replacing-system-classes.html), by Andrey Petrov.

Comment: You're talking about a binary replacement of the library?